# Default frame to display in a ggplotly animation

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

Does anyone know how to set initial frame with `ggplotly()`?

The initial states of the 4 points is `1:4` and the slider is adding numbers `-10:10`.

Let's say I have this animated plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

add <- rep(seq(-10, 10, by = .5), each = 4)
x <- 1:4 + add

df <- data.frame(x = x, y = 1, add = add)

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(frame = add),
             col = rep(c("yellow", "green", "red", "blue"), length(unique(add))),
             size = 5) +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank())

ggplotly(plot)
```

I would like the plot to start at x = 1:4 (frame 21) instead of x = -9:-6 (frame 1).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It could be a matter of how `add` is ordered in your data frame.

```
df$add <- rev(df$add)
# ... same code as before
ggplotly(plot)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I realise I didn't really explain my problem clearly enough. I tried this before but it doesn't really work. You can only flip the order around, custom order (e.g., starting in the middle) won't really work. Besides, as you can see in your screengrab, the slider is still in the -10 position so the plot is not showing what the slider indicates. The initial states of the 4 points is `1:4` and the slider is adding numbers `-10:10`.